# Minimized WinForms app restoring to Normal on second launch

Tags: c#, winforms

First of all, I want to explain the "second launch": I use the [`SingleInstanceController` approach](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx) to make it possible to call my app's `EXE` file, and accept arguments.

That way other apps, or users can tell the application to take a specific action.

The app is set to start with a `WindowState` of `Minimized`, and only if the user clicks the tray icon it restores to `Normal`.

But what I'm seeing is, that the first time I launch the application it stays minimized. Then when I call the EXE file for the second time, it restores to a normal window state.

I have no code that alters the window state.

I suspect this is because something else is triggering the restore.

The code of my `SingleInstanceController` looks like this:

```
public class SingleInstanceController : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    public SingleInstanceController()
    {
        IsSingleInstance = true;

        StartupNextInstance += this_StartupNextInstance;
    }

    void this_StartupNextInstance(object sender, StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = MainForm as Form1;
        string command = e.CommandLine[1];

        switch (command.ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            case "makecall":
                string phoneNumber = e.CommandLine[2];
                PhoneAppHelper.MakePhoneCall(phoneNumber);
                break;
            default:
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Argument not supported");
                break;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
        MainForm = new Form1();
    }
}
```

On my form, I have a listbox to show connected devices (USB), and a multiline textbox to show some activity, most for debug/information purposes.

Could the interaction with the controls on the form cause the restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the default behavior for WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnStartupNextInstance().  You can simply fix that by overriding the method instead of using the event.  Do note that you probably still want this to happen when you have a message to display.  So make it look similar to this:

```
protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e) {
    //...
    switch (command.ToLowerInvariant()) {
        // etc..
        default:
            base.OnStartupNextInstance(e);   // Brings it to the front
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Argument not supported");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: AWESOME! What was weird before was, that it was *only* the second launch that restored the window state. After manually minimizing the window, the 3rd, 4th... nth launch kept the window minimized.